# Factor Levels and Modelling in R

Tags: r, lm

The following code runs a very simple `lm()` and tries to summarise the results (factor level, coefficient) in a small data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(star_sign = c("Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces"),
                 y = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.3, 1.8, 1.6, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.5, 1.3))

levels(df$star_sign) #alphabetical order

# fit a simple linear model

my_lm <- lm(y ~ 1 + star_sign, data = df)
summary(my_lm) # intercept is based on first level of factor, aquarius

# I want the levels to work properly 1..12 = Aries, Taurus...Pisces so I'm going to redefine the factor levels

df$my_levels <- c("Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces")

df$star_sign <- factor(df$star_sign, levels = df$my_levels)

my_lm <- lm(y ~ 1 + star_sign_, data = df)
summary(my_lm) # intercept is based on first level of factor which is now Aries

# but for my model fit I want the reference level to be Virgo (because reasons)

df$star_sign_2 <- relevel(df$star_sign, ref = "Virgo")

my_lm <- lm(y ~ 1 + star_sign_2, data = df)
summary(my_lm)

df_results <- data.frame(factor_level = names(my_lm$coefficients), coeff = my_lm$coefficients )

# tidy up
rownames(df_results) <- 1:12
df_results$factor_level <- as.factor(gsub("star_sign_2", "", df_results$factor_level))

# change label of "(Intercept)" to "Virgo"
df_results$factor_level <- plyr::revalue(df_results$factor_level, c("(Intercept)" = "Virgo"))

levels(df_results$factor_level) # the levels are alphabetical + Virgo at the front (not same as display order from lm)
```

The factor levels aren't in the right order: I want to sort `df_results` so that the star signs appear in the same order as they do originally (Aries, Taurus...Pisces), as captured in the `df$my_levels` column. I don't think I have a good understanding of manipulating factors and their labels/levels, etc. so I'm struggling to know how to do this.

Also this is quite a long-winded and clumsy bit of code. Are there more concise ways to do this sort of thing?

Thank you.

(ps mathematically the model is obviously trivial, but that's ok for these purposes - I'm just interested in how to manipulate the outputs)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach the model coefficient extraction, using the `broom` package (and `dplyr`):

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
broom::tidy(my_lm) %>%
  mutate(term = sub("star_sign_2", "", term),
         term = ifelse(term == "(Intercept)", "Virgo", term),
         term = factor(term, levels = unique(term)))
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
   <fct>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 Virgo          1.6         NaN       NaN     NaN
 2 Aries         -0.500       NaN       NaN     NaN
 3 Taurus        -0.4         NaN       NaN     NaN
 4 Gemini        -0.2         NaN       NaN     NaN
 5 Cancer        -0.300       NaN       NaN     NaN
 6 Leo            0.20        NaN       NaN     NaN
 7 Libra         -0.2         NaN       NaN     NaN
 8 Scorpio       -0.3         NaN       NaN     NaN
 9 Sagittarius   -0.4         NaN       NaN     NaN
10 Capricorn     -0.500       NaN       NaN     NaN
11 Aquarius      -0.1         NaN       NaN     NaN
12 Pisces        -0.300       NaN       NaN     NaN
```

Setting the `levels = unique(term)` is a nice trick for putting the levels in the order in which they occur.

The other advice I have is to keep a vector of the levels in the order you want **not** in the data frame, and then refer to that whenever you need to establish order. For example,

```
astro_order = c("Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces")

# messy but effective:
astro_order_virgo1 = factor(astro_order, levels = astro_order) %>% 
  relevel("Virgo") %>%
  levels()
```

So then you could replace the last step above with `term = factor(term, levels = astro_order_virgo1)`.

This approach of keeping the level order separate is good because (a) it won't change if you reorder your data frame, and (b) it works just as well if your data frame is long and you have repeat entries of your factor levels.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you needed to do this is pretty straightforward.
Just add the following code at the end of your script. I also encourage you to dive into dplyr or tidyverse.
Let me know if you have any questions :)

```
## ADDED: 

#WE CREATE AN ID to maintain order in df_results 
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)


library(dplyr)
#Perform left _ join (you could also do inner or right, you'll get the same result in this case )
df_results = left_join(df_results,df, by=c('factor_level'='star_sign_2'))
df_results = df_results %>% arrange(id)

# select desired columns (optionally) 
df_results = df_results %>% select(factor_level,coeff) 


head(df_results)

 factor_level coeff
1        Aries  -0.5
2       Taurus  -0.4
3       Gemini  -0.2
4       Cancer  -0.3
5          Leo   0.2
6        Virgo   1.6
```